# Getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for a class annotated with @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an external library that is making use of a class that is annotated with @ConfigurationProperties. However when I am making use of this in my project it it gives `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. How can I resolve this ?

The hierarchy looks something like this

```
@Test //class where I am trying to autowire B
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {config.class})
public class A extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

@Autowire
private B b;
}
...}
```

```
@Configuration
@Import({config2.class})
public class B extends AnotherClass {...}
```

```
//cannot edit these files
public abstract class AnotherClass extends AbstractConfig {
```

```
//cannot edit these files
@Configuration
@Import({C.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({xyz.class})
public abstract class AbstractConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport implements AbstractConfigInterface {..}
```

```
//cannot edit these files
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({Properties.class})
public class C {
    public C() {
    }
}
```

```
@ConfigurationProperties(
    prefix = "abc"
)
public class Properties {...}
```

The exception I am getting is like `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'Properties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com....Properties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot features, whereas your test is a plain Spring test. Hence no Spring BOot feature and thus no `@ConfigurationProperties` support.

Comment: @M.Deinum oh okk... is there a way to use these libraries without breaking my code ?

Comment: YOu have to use Spring Boot for this, if you cannot use this you cannot use `@ConfigurationProperties`.